# Get Website Permission with Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, user-permissions

I am trying to figure out how to get the well known **Website Permission Lists** with Powershell. I tried several methods. The best solution seems to me to try something like `$spWeb.RoleAssignments` but this delivers me not only the users and groups with **ist** permissions on the **spweb**. I also get the roleassignments from the unique lists and libraries on the website.

Do you have suggestions how can I filter to check if a user has, for example, read permission on the **spweb** (without regarding the lists and subwebs)?

My target is to check the **spweb** and **ist** subwebs and unique lists and libraries step by step for a user(group) like "NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users". Then I want to remove the roleassignment and add a new roleassignment with a group of my colleagues, so that not everybody can see the content. The uniqe permission structure should remain.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if a user has specific permission level using SPWeb.DoesUserHavePermissions method:

public bool DoesUserHavePermissions(
    string login,
    SPBasePermissions permissionMask
)

[SPWeb.DoesUserHavePermissions method (String, SPBasePermissions)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms441848.aspx)

```
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sp/"))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            // Make sure the current user can enumerate permissions.
            if (web.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPBasePermissions.EnumeratePermissions))
            {
                // Specify the permission to check.
                SPBasePermissions permissionToCheck = SPBasePermissions.ViewListItems;
                Console.WriteLine("The following users have {0} permission:", permissionToCheck);

                // Check the permissions of users who are explicitly assigned permissions.
                SPUserCollection users = web.Users;
                foreach (SPUser user in users)
                {
                    string login = user.LoginName;
                    if (web.DoesUserHavePermissions(login, permissionToCheck))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(login);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
```